# The configuration section 'security' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am trying to add to the web.config the following section:

```
<location path="Test.aspx">
<system.web>
 <security>
    <authentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.web>
</location>
```

But I get error "The configuration section 'security' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's been a long time since I edited a webconfig, but shouldn't you have a <section> tag somewhere? The error message seems to indicate this...

Comment: Can you add the rest of your web.config along with where you are trying to add this? Hard to tell without seeing the rest of it.

Comment: Maybe this validator can help you https://elmah.io/tools/configvalidator/

Comment: @Selthien  The web.config is long.  I am trying to add the above section AFTEr the </system.web> tag.  And it does not matter if I add the above section in the middle of the <system.web></system.web> or after.    The fact is that without the above section, no error.  Thanks.